# Matlab computation of L2 norm is very slow

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, julia, linear-algebra

I have the following MATLAB snippet:

```
>> R = randn(3000,6000);   % build a random 3000 by 6000 matrix
>> tic; norm(R, 1); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.005586 seconds.
>> tic; norm(R, 2); toc;
Elapsed time is 3.019667 seconds.
>> tic; norm(R, inf); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.005393 seconds.
>>
```

My question is, why would the L2 norm computation be that much slower than the L1 or L infinity norm? This is a random matrix for testing purposes, of course, but for the actual matrix in my work I can see a similar pattern in terms of elapsed time.

However, on Julia, the results are as follows

```
julia> @time norm(R, 1);
  0.007156 seconds (1 allocation: 16 bytes)

julia> @time norm(R, 2);
  0.009142 seconds (1 allocation: 16 bytes)

julia> @time norm(R, Inf);
  0.034633 seconds (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
```

This makes no sense at all. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Be aware that in Julia it is much better to do timings using `@btime` from `BenchmarkTools.jl` to ensure you don't accidentally capture compilation time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I invite you to read the [documentation for `norm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html). It is a good idea to always read the documentation to a function and not make assumptions about what it does. In short, with a matrix input, `norm` computes the matrix norm:

1. `norm(R,1)` is the maximum absolute column sum of `R`.
2. `norm(R,Inf)` is the maximum absolute row sum of `R`.
3. `norm(R,2)` is approximately `max(svd(R))`.

The 1-norm and infinity-norm of the matrix are computed in a similar way, and are therefore expected to be similar in cost. Computing the sum over rows or columns, and the max of the result, is quite cheap.

The 2-norm of the matrix in contrast requires a singular value decomposition, which is significantly more expensive.

In Julia, `norm` computes the vector norm. To compute a matrix norm, use [`opnorm`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#LinearAlgebra.opnorm).

To compute the vector norm of rows or columns of a matrix in MATLAB, use [`vecnorm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vecnorm.html) (since R2017b). To compute the norm of the vectorized matrix, use `norm(R(:))`.

---

PS: The real question is why is the infinity-norm in Julia so slow? It should be cheaper than the 1-norm and much cheaper than the 2-norm!

Comment: Using `BenchmarkTools` like @ColinTBowers points out, the times are: 1-norm=17ms, 2-norm=23ms, inf-norm=29ms. So it isn't as starkly slow as the times in the question. As for why it isn't faster, it looks like 1-norm and 2-norm call specialized BLAS methods, whereas inf-norm only has a generic Julia implementation.

Comment: Interestingly, the Infinity norm is 2.3x slower than obvious `maximum(abs, R)`.

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/43190 fixes this.